# What is the lastest stable kernel and how to install it?

Tags: kernel, 16.04

I face a problem with installing kernel 4.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 . Someone said because it was unstable. So What is the latest stable version of kernel and how to install it.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-generic

Comment: Latest stable kernel as on 26-May-2016 is 4.4.0-22-generic. just doing `sudo apt-get distupgrade` should install it.

Comment: Depends how you define "stable kernel".

Comment: @fkraiem I would define "stable" as the "mainline version" and "unstable" as the "release candidate version". That said bugs can appear in any version.

Comment: See also this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/924814/is-it-risky-to-update-my-linux-kernel-to-latest-stable-version-when-running-ubun/924830#924830

Answer (score 8):

In your terminal type

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Then type `sudo apt-get install linux-image-<latest version>`

Answer (score 3):

The risk of crashes is highest with release candidate new kernels at this time *February 4, 2017* version 4.10 release candidate **4.10-rc6** is the newest. Mainline kernels are considered **stable** and the latest version here is **4.9.8** which I installed a few hours ago.

## Finding the right kernel

Rather than the link you are using, go to ([kernel.ubuntu.com - Kernel PPA Mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)) and press the <kbd>End</kbd> key:

[image: Mainline kernel 1]

Now click on the link `4.9.8` and this screen appears:

[image: mainline kernel 2]

Note the links with the black airbrush marks. These are the three we will download for ***Ubuntu 16.04 64-Bit*** using ***Intel or AMD*** processors.

## Installing using Terminal

Open a terminal session with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and use:

```
cd Downloads # Assuming this is your browser download directory
rm *.deb     # This erases all *.deb files, ensure only old ones are here
```

Now toggle back to the download screen above and single-click on all three of the `.deb` kernel downloads. After downloads complete (you'll see status in your browser) toggle back to terminal session and use:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
rm *.deb
sudo reboot
```

Voila! - you are running the latest kernel when first option in grub boot menu is selected. Your older kernel versions are still available under grub's **Advanced Options** menu.

After installing the newest kernel a dozen times you will ask the question "*How do I remove older kernel versions?*" and you will find those answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once/892077#892077) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) in ***Ask Ubuntu***.

Comment: If this process is followed does it mean that the kernel would have to be manually upgraded thereafter? How can one switch back to the auto upgraded kernel later on?

Comment: Yes manually installed kernels have to be manually upgraded and manually removed (see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once/892077#892077). Auto-upgraded kernels continue to be installed and are available when rebooting from the ***Advanced Options*** menu within grub.

Comment: does this kernel has sleep-wakeup issue ?

Comment: @bicepjai There are hundreds of kernel versions you can download.  The one above `4.9.8` just happened to be the most current at the time. Since then there have been `4.10.xx`, `4.11.xx` and now we are on `4.12.xx`. Each version could potentially have it's own issues. Generally most sleep/wake (aka suspend/resume) issues are through your system setup in `ACPI` or `systemd` or `gsettings`. There are times when changing a kernel version helps and other times when it doesn't. You can post a question in Ask Ubuntu with your specific problems and mention your current kernel version there.