# My Laptop is not starting after upgrade ubuntu 16.04 (Kernel 4.8.0-38 to 04.10.0-36)

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel

After reading and reviewing a lot about Ubuntu finally today i installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS into my laptop. After installation I ran the update and upgrade commands which completed successfully. When I restarted my laptop,  it froze at the startup screen.

I pressed the power button for few seconds and turned the laptop off. In the next boot I selected advanced options and found two kernel options:

- 1st one is 4.10.0-33
- 2nd one is 4.8.0-38

I am able to start and boot using 4.8.0-38 but not able to start with 4.10.0-36. I have also formatted my laptop twice but i am facing the problem after complete update.

So friends please help me to come out of this problem. I would also like to say that I am very new here.

below is my system details.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           382M  6.3M  376M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       113G  4.9G  102G   5% /
tmpfs           1.9G   34M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           382M   80K  382M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda4       200G   72G  129G  36% /media/ali/Software
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are the hardware specs? Have you installed a graphics driver manually?

Comment: I am using HP Follio 9470m, 4gb of ram, intel core i5, 500 gb hdd. I have not installed any driver manually.

Answer (score 0):

My first concern would be the next update installs 4.10.0-37 which is also broken. Then through auto-remove you loose your only working kernel which is 4.8.0-38.

The first thing I would do is install a kernel version which can't be auto-removed and must be manually removed. I would suggest [4.9.45 mainline build](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9.45/) because 4.9 is LTS (Long Term Support) for about 5 years I believe.

The instructions for installing a stable mainline kernel are fairly straightforward: [What is the lastest stable kernel and how to install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777627/what-is-the-lastest-stable-kernel-and-how-to-install-it/926287#926287)

Another kernel you can install to test version 4.10 compatibility is [4.10.17 mainline build](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777627/what-is-the-lastest-stable-kernel-and-how-to-install-it/926287#926287).

Finally an extra version of 4.8 that can't be removed automatically is [4.8.17 mainline build](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.17/)

Keep in mind each kernel consumes about 50 MB in your `/boot` directory and about 350 MB in `/lib` and `/etc` sub-directories.

Later after auto-installed kernels are working reliably you can [remove manually installed kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu/892096#892096). I have lots of disk space and keep about 20 kernels installed for testing purposes but that's not everyone's cup of tea.

Hopefully your problems wiht `4.10.0-36` is a one-off glitch and will never be repeated. First things first though is to protect your system to ensure you can always boot successfully.

Please keep us posted on progress.

Comment: I have followed the link and process which you have provided, but nothing worked for me, I have also installed the kernels but no luck.  may be it's because i am not proficient in Linux and missing any step.
So now i want to remove that 4.10.0-33 update and want to use the old one i.e. 4.8.0-36

Comment: Installing the backup kernels should have gone smoothly. What error messages did you get whilst trying to install? That may shed light on what went wrong with 4.10 automatic kernel upgrade. Perhaps you are low on disk space in `/boot` or something. I thought it was `4.10.0-36` update installed earlier not `4.10.0-33` as you say now?

Comment: After following your instructions i have installed the kernel you said. I didn't got any error or problem. After installing kernel it asked me to restart and i restarted the laptop but the problem is not solved, again I have to start with advance option

Comment: @SabirAli Which kernel version did you install? `4.9.45` or all three? Are all three versions mainline kernel versions broken?

Comment: I had installed 4.9.45, but now I have installed Synaptic Package Manager and removed Linux Kernel 4.10.0-33 and now laptop is working fine. It took me approx 24 hour to get the solution.

And I would like to thank you too because from starting you are helping me.
Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @SabirAli You are most welcome for the help. I'm still concerned about the health of your machine and why `4.10.0-36` automatic kernel upgrade failed because it might happen again. Can you include the output of `df -h` command into your question?

Comment: I have included the details you asked into my question please check, and please let me know if you need any more details.