# Xubuntu booting up with black Screen.

Tags: boot, xubuntu, suspend, hibernate

OS: xubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
kernel version: 4.13.0-36-generic

When I boot up, I get my BIOS splash screen followed by shiny black screen comes,after that screen blacks out. I have to close laptop Lid to force hibernation and then reopen the lid and then I get the login screen. With this version of kernel I was not able to find any bugs related to hibernation. If I attach a external monitor then I get the login screen directly.  I had similar problem with Ubuntu 16.04.4, there was a dark purple light(related to ubuntu) and then the screen blacks out. Had to follow the similar lid process to get the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by following the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777627/what-is-the-lastest-stable-kernel-and-how-to-install-it) by installing kernel version 4.15.10-041510-generic.